# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows. If I removed the select top 1 in my query

Tags: sql

This is my current query.

```
insert into @FinalResultTable 
select * from (
select 
    (
        select top 1 sortID from @DataSetWithSortID sortID 
        where 
            Customer_ID = sortID.customerID and Vessel = sortID.VesselCode 
            and Voyage = sortId.VoyageNo and sortID.ChargeCode = '*first-12200 Receivables : Contract Assets'
    ) Posting_ID, 
    'GL' DataCategory, 
     POL_ETS, 
    null BLNo, 
    '*first-12200 Receivables : Contract Assets' Account, 
    --Debit, Credit, 
    sum(credit) as Debit, 0 as Credit, 
    Customer_ID, Vessel, Voyage,null RevenueBranch,null POLCode,--'' Shipment_Type, '' Shipment_Condition, '' Location_Of_Invoicing, '' Location_Of_Payment, '' [User], 
    --'' Reason_For_Correction, '' Locked_By_User,
     null Accounting_Period, 0 IsPosted, null Date_Ingested, null Date_Posted,Null User_Posted
from @DetailedTable 
group by customer_id, vessel, voyage,POL_ETS


union all 


select 
    (
        select top 1 sortID from @DataSetWithSortID sortID 
        where 
            Customer_ID = sortID.customerID and Vessel = sortID.VesselCode 
            and Voyage = sortId.VoyageNo and Account = sortID.ChargeCode 
    ) Posting_ID, 
    'GL' DataCategory, 
    POL_ETS, 
    null BLNo, 
    Account, 
    0 as Debit, sum(credit) as Credit,
    Customer_ID, Vessel, Voyage,RevenueBranch,POLCode, --'' Shipment_Type, '' Shipment_Condition, '' Location_Of_Invoicing, '' Location_Of_Payment, '' [User], 
    --'' Reason_For_Correction, '' Locked_By_User, 
     null Accounting_Period, 0 IsPosted, null Date_Ingested, null Date_Posted,Null User_Posted
from @DetailedTable 
group by Customer_ID, Vessel, Voyage,POL_ETS, account ,RevenueBranch,POLCode
) q1
```

The problem with this is that it gets only the top sortID not the second see attached screenshot.

[image]

I am expecting that the sort ID would align to the sort ID in the query. I think the top 1 is selecting the top / first sort ID. The second problem is that when i removed the top 1 there is a multiple sub query issue. because one of my table has multiple charge code = one description which I think is the issue. How can I resolve this?

Comment: From site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc**.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) - e.g. I cannot see that image

Comment: Regarding the tag "SQL" if you hover over that tag please read its description: "*Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), **use that DBMS's tag instead**. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL*"

Comment: To understand your problem we need sample data and the "expected result" from that sample. Ideally in the form of sql inserts or ascii tables that can easily be parsed. Or, use https://dbfiddle.uk to set-up the sample tables and provide that url.

Comment: Okay. I have a sortID tagging and I would like it to reflect here in my second query which is the final table.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: LEFT JOIN the subquery instead, and skip TOP.

Comment: How will I use the left join? what columns?